# how to create installation exe file with these specifications?

Tags: file, installation, exe

I need to create a windows installation file that installs a folder in a specific folder on the pc and hides it. after hiding it, it must create a link to a file (a specific file that is in the hidden folder) and move it to a specific folder on the pc. there should not be the possibility of the user selecting the installation folder.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to create some kind of malware.

Comment: i'm just trying to learn